# How do I suppress "has no attribute" errors from mypy when assigning a new attribute to a function?

Tags: python, mypy, typechecking, python-typing, static-initialization

I often use the following idiom for static initialization:

```
def compute_answer() -> int:
    if compute_answer.ret is None:
        # Do stuff that only happens the first time
        compute_answer.ret = 42
    return compute_answer.ret

compute_answer.ret = None
```

However, type checking with mypy gives the following errors:

```
compute.py:2: error: "Callable[[], int]" has no attribute "ret"
compute.py:4: error: "Callable[[], int]" has no attribute "ret"
compute.py:5: error: "Callable[[], int]" has no attribute "ret"
compute.py:7: error: "Callable[[], int]" has no attribute "ret"
```

How can I suppress these errors, especially locally (e.g., just this function/attribute)?

Comment: I think:  # type: ignore

Comment: @hussic Yes that works, but you have to put that on every line where the attribute appears.

Comment: Could you just use the `@functools.cache` decorator?

Comment: @Samwise In this case yes, but there are other valid reasons to store one or more attributes in a function that wouldn't be covered by a caching decorator.

Comment: I'd be curious to know what they are -- I can't actually think of anything you could do by monkeypatching the function that you couldn't do some other way that would both be more mypy-friendly (and therefore more typo-proof) and more compact.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the decorator returning custom `Protocol` for function objects. Like so:

```
from typing import Any, Protocol, Optional


class ComputeAnswerProto(Protocol):
    ret: Optional[int]

    def __call__(self) -> int: ...


def compute_decorator(func: Any) -> ComputeAnswerProto:
    return func


@compute_decorator
def compute_answer() -> int:
    if compute_answer.ret is None:
        # Do stuff that only happens the first time
        compute_answer.ret = 42
    return compute_answer.ret


compute_answer.ret = None
```

Comment: At this point it seems like mypy is not helping us to write better, more understandable code, but adding needless complexity.